# How to repeat loop for same input multiple times

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i wanted to take same input but i want to assign aggregate score of 2nd run to ag2
here is my code

```
int c1=0, c2=0, c3=0, c4=0, c5=0, c6=0;
    for (int id = 1; id <= 5; id = id + 1){

        cout << "Enter student id and marks of student courses";
            cin >> id >> c1 >> c2 >> c3 >> c4 >> c5;
            int ag1 = 0,ag2=0,ag3=0,ag4=0,ag5=0;
            ag1 = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5;
```

Can anyone guide me?
Basically program is about taking 5 students 5 courses and than calculate agg score and tell who got higher.

Comment: Sounds like you need an array and possibly a class to represent a student.

Comment: @NathanOliver i havent learn array yet. You sure there isnt any other way using loop. this program can be done without loop but i have to do it with loop

Answer (score 0):

I won't code it for you, but I can give you a few tips.

If you are going to do a `cin >` of a variable, you don't need to have it initialized at 0 before. You could just declare them as `int c1, c2,..`

In for loops, we usually start with our counter at 0, not 1. This is because when we iterate through array structures, they begin in 0, so we go from "id" to < our limit. If you begin in one, you'd have to start with "id - 1" to iterate through an array.

This `id = id + 1` we usually type as `id++`. Its much shorter and intuitive.

Now for your problem. If you want to do the same for ag1...ag5, you'll need to put your "ag" variables inside an array. You can do this in many ways. One is:

```
int ags[5];
```

Now you can do `ags[0]=15;` and from there on, in the array "ags", position 0, there is a "15". To get this "15", you do `int oneAg = ags[0];` and in "oneAg" there'd be a 15.

If in this example you substitute 0 for your for loop index variable, in your case "id" (making it start in 0), you can save your 5 ags effectively. Be careful though, that you can't do a `cin >> id` inside your loop, or you will break the loop. Use a different variable for Id you read.

Have fun coding. We all, even those who know a LOT, start like you are as now!

Answer (score 0):

When you must do it without arrays, you have to read one students mark per loop and remember the best

like so (pseudo code):

```
int best_student = 0;
int best_marksum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< 5 ; ++i)
{
    // read students id
    int marksum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        // read student mark
       marksum += mark;
    }
    if (marksum > best_marksum)
    {
        best_student = student_id;
        best_marksum = marksum;
    }

}
// finally print the result
```

That should be what you need toi figure it yourself